# Методы и объекты в java

Tags: java

Методы не работают.
Как правильно будет?

```
public class Dice{
  public static void main( String[] args){ 
    // constants

    // variables
    Die die1;
    Die die2;
    die1 = new Die();
   die2 = new Die(); 
  }
  // program code
  public int rollDice(){
    die1.roll();
    die2.roll();
    return     die1.getFaceValue() + die2.getFaceValue();
  }
  public int getDie1FaceValue(){
    return     die1.getFaceValue();
  }
  public int getDie2FaceValue(){
    return     die2.getFaceValue();
  }
  public int getDiceTotal(){
    return     die1.getFaceValue() + die2.getFaceValue();
  }
  public String toString(){
    return "Die face number is";
  }
}
```

где, roll() это метод в классе Die который дает случайное число от 1 до 6; getFaceValue() это метод в классе Die который возвращает это число.

Comment: Чтобы проверить их работоспособность, как минимум, их нужно вызвать, чего Вы не делаете.

Comment: И вообще, данный код не скомпилируется, так как Вы пытаетесь обратиться к переменным вне их области видимости.

Comment: @post_zeew Методы внутри main тоже не получится написать. Как нужно написать, чтобы переменные были в области видимости методов?

Comment: *Объявлять методы* внутри других методов не нужно, их нужно *вызывать*. Сделайте Ваши объекты полями класса.

Comment: Это не работоспособный код. Трудно даже сказать, в чем именно состоит проблема. У меня такое ощущение, что вы не понимаете каких-то фундаментальных вещей - классы, их методы, их поля, области видимости. Я бы советовал почитать какие-нибудь начального уровня книжки по Java.

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите переменные `die1` и `die2` из статического метода main в поля класса `Dice`:

```
public class Dice{

    Die die1 = new Die();
    Die die2 = new Die();

    public static void main( String[] args){ 
        // constants

        // variables
        Dice dice = new Dice();
        System.out.println(dice.rollDice());
    }

    //Другие вспомогательные методы
    //...
}
```